# How to fix "Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process" when running a Django application?

Tags: django, apache

I have a Django application that is running on an Apache web server. However, the application throws of the error (found in the error log):

```
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'djangoproject': 
[Sat Dec 14 06:53:16.317958 2019] [wsgi:error] ... Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process
```

My application works but it's turning out to be really slow. This happens very often - especially when I keep refreshing my template. I tried looking into the error and expanding the header limit size in the Apache config file but it didn't resolve my issue.

**This is my Apache config file:**

```
Alias /static /var/myproject/myapp/static
<Directory /var/myproject/myapp/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /var/myproject/myapp/media
<Directory /var/myproject/myapp/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/myproject/myapp/myapp> #wsgi file lives inside here
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
<Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/myproject/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess djangoproject python-path=/var/myproject/myapp python-home=/var/myproject/myapp/venv

WSGIProcessGroup djangoproject
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@danny_boy, I think you will get some steps in here for **WSGI error** issue:  **Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process**.

Some guys suggesting to add a line in **httpd.conf**

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Also some other guys suggestions may help you to exactly figure out your issue:

https://serverfault.com/questions/844761/wsgi-truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process